# Renderizar 2 Htmls, 2 reactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Estoy intentando renderizar dos reactDom en dos archivos HTML distintos (respectivamente). *Utilizando webpack*.

[image: Archivos Html]

dentro esta:

[app.html]

```
  <body>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="../../build/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

[setup.html]

```
  <body>
    <div id="setup-root"></div>
    <script src="../../build/js/setup.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**En dos archivos distintos intento renderizarlos**

[index.js]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../views/App";
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[setup.js]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Setup from "../views/Setup";
ReactDOM.render(<Setup />, document.getElementById("setup-root"));
```

He separado los ReactDOM.render en archivos distintos, el index.js se encarga de renderizar el index.html, el cual es la pagina principal, y el setup.js el otro archivo. Y necesito hacerlo en 2 html distintos.

Este es mi archivo de configuración de webpack (no se si el problema este ahí)

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    index: "./dist/react/index.js",
    setup: "./dist/react/setup.index.js",
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  target: "electron-renderer",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                  targets: {
                    esmodules: true,
                  },
                },
              ],
              "@babel/preset-react",
            ],
            plugins: [
              [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                {
                  loose: true,
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: [/\.s[ac]ss$/i, /\.css$/i],
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "js"),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          name: "commons",
          chunks: "initial",
          minChunks: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

***Pero sale todo en blanco***, no hay un error ni nada, y ya revise que el HTML esta leyendo los Js correctamente. ***Posdata: "Estoy corriendo React dentro de Electron"***

[image: Imagen del error]

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs no soporta multiples html es para hacer single page aplication. Usa solo un index.html donde renderizara todo. Puedes usar react-router para manejar las rutas y renderizar dependiendo la ruta, por ejemplo la parte /admin renderizas un componente admin. Con wepback creo que puedes crear que carge otro html en tal ruta pero tienes que crear otra applicacion de react tener 2 aplicaciones creo que asi se podria ya que react usa solo un index.html y nada mas.